# Allow Consumer of an API to access view jQuery getJSON

Tags: json, cross-domain

I currently have an API that I allow consumers to use via an API key. They can make calls in cURL or any other scripting languages - but they can't make calls view $.getJSON(). No results are returned, only a HTTP 200 code.

Do I need to add a crossdomain.xml file to my servers' root directory or is there another way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run some JavaScript on a browser that does a request to a different domain, it's simply not possible due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You can work around this by setting up a proxy on the domain serving the web content which accesses your API on behalf of the JavaScript.

crossdomain.xml is specific to Flash and won't affect JavaScript.

Comment: Why is it possible to do $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/", function(data) { //something }); ? You should be able to do $.getJSON to another domain to get the results - correct?

Answer (score 0):

The callback function passed with $.getJSON must satisfy two criteria:

- Its arguments must be in the correct order
- It must have a receiver function on the server of the API which expects it

Here is a diagram:

```
CLIENT                   SERVER
------                   ------

Makes URL request        Looks up function matching this URL

Executes asynchonously   If found, executes function asynchonously

Returns from callback    Returns data from server side function, or error
```